# Reassigning Deleted Array and Reading Free'd Memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, valgrind

I'm relatively new to C++ and Valgrind. I develop on a mac, so it's very possible that I access memory that I shouldn't and the program doesn't crash. Previously, I wrote some code for an array-based list data structure like the C++ vector. I extended that structure to create an array-based circular queue. I ran unit tests in Xcode and in terminal, and did not get any problems.

Valgrind, on the other hand, has issues with my code. I believe I have narrowed the problem down to the following code, which is primarily used to resize the array when it gets full.

(I come from Java, please excuse the style)

```
private:

/**
 * the maximum number of elements the current list can contain if it is not
 * resized
 */
int m_arraySize;

/**
 * the actual list of elements in this list
 */
E* m_values;


/**
 * Copies the contents of this array into a new array and replaces the old
 * array-based list with the new array. If the new array has smaller size
 * than the old array, then elements that do not fit into the new array
 * are discarded. If the new array size is less than 1, 1 is automatically
 * used as the new array size
 *
 * @param newArraySize       the new size of the elements array
 */
void useResizedArray( int newArraySize ) {
    int arraySize = newArraySize;
    if ( arraySize < 1 ) {
        arraySize = 1;
    }
    E* newArr = new E[ arraySize ];

    //copy elements into the new array
    int smallestSize = min( m_arraySize , arraySize );
    for ( int i=0 ; i<smallestSize ; i++ ) {
        newArr[ i ] = m_values[ i ];
    }

    //free memory of the old array
    delete[] m_values;

    //update the list to have the new array and the new size
    m_values = newArr;
    m_arraySize = arraySize;
}
```

When I run my unit tests for the array-based list, they all pass and Valgrind does not complain at all. I also subclass the array-based list to create a circular array-based queue. When I run my units tests for the queue, they all pass and there are no memory leaks; however, Valgrind says that I access free'd memory a lot. The first error is reported as follows (I suppressed all but the first 2 tests, which cause this first error):

```
==17904== Invalid read of size 4
==17904==    at 0x10001CA34: ArrayList<int>::set(int, int const&) (ArrayList.h:286)
==17904==    by 0x1000727E3: ArrayQueue<int>::offer(int const&) (ArrayQueue.h:126)
==17904==    by 0x10006191D: ArrayQueueTests::testOffer() (ArrayQueueTests.cpp:49)
==17904==    by 0x100060C47: ArrayQueueTests::test() (ArrayQueueTests.cpp:13)
==17904==    by 0x100001122: main (main.cpp:41)
==17904==  Address 0x1000e6c90 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==17904==    at 0x4D9D: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:477)
==17904==    by 0x10001D416: ArrayList<int>::useResizedArray(int) (ArrayList.h:86)
==17904==    by 0x10007326E: ArrayList<int>::ensureCapacity(int) (ArrayList.h:377)
==17904==    by 0x1000727B1: ArrayQueue<int>::offer(int const&) (ArrayQueue.h:124)
==17904==    by 0x10006191D: ArrayQueueTests::testOffer() (ArrayQueueTests.cpp:49)
==17904==    by 0x100060C47: ArrayQueueTests::test() (ArrayQueueTests.cpp:13)
==17904==    by 0x100001122: main (main.cpp:41)
==17904== 
ArrayQueue unit tests finished. Passed 2 of 2 tests.
==17904== 
==17904== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17904==     in use at exit: 29,316 bytes in 377 blocks
==17904==   total heap usage: 482 allocs, 105 frees, 36,032 bytes allocated
==17904== 
==17904== LEAK SUMMARY:
==17904==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17904==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17904==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17904==    still reachable: 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks
==17904==         suppressed: 25,220 bytes in 376 blocks
==17904== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==17904== 
==17904== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17904== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

At ArrayList.h:286, I execute the simple statement

```
    m_values[ index ] = value;
```

after checking that it is in the bounds `(0<=index && index<m_arraySize)` of the array-based list.

Valgrind claims that I free'd the memory at ArrayList.h:86, which is the following code:

```
    delete[] m_values;
```

But I'm pretty certain I reassigned m_values right after I deleted it. So, I played around to see what would happen. I commented out the line

```
    delete[] m_values;
```

and the memory access error disappeared; however, after commenting out the delete, Valgrind detected memory leaks. Thus, I concluded that the `delete[] m_values` was causing Valgrind to report a memory leak problem.

I was wondering if there was something `delete[]` did to the pointer `m_values` that no longer allows me to use it. If I cannot `delete[]` the pointer, is there any way to avoid the memory leak? I am also confused because my current searching suggests that `m_values` can be reassigned and reused after executing `delete[] m_values`.

I am also considering that it could be a problem with some other part of my code, but I would be surprised if it was a side effect of something else that caused Valgrind to point out ArrayList.h:86.

Or (very unlikely) could it be a problem with Valgrind and the code is correct? I have tried putting gibberish into the `m_values` array after deleting it, but before reassigning it. This way, if I did access free'd memory, it would have been altered from before it was freed. The unit tests still passed.

Is there anything that seems to stick out like a blatant mistake? Thank you for your time and help.

EDIT:

I will add in some more code. Here are the relevant parts of ArrayList.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ArrayList.h"
#include "ArrayQueue.h"
#include <string>
using std::string;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    string expected;
    string found;
    string errorMessage = "ArrayQueue offer() failed!";
    ArrayQueue< int > test;

    //test empty queue
    test.clear();
    expected = "[]";
    found = test.toString();
    //evaluateTest( expected , found , errorMessage );

    //test 1 element
    test.clear();
    test.offer( 1 );
    expected = "[1]";
    found = test.toString();
    //evaluateTest( expected , found , errorMessage );

    //test multiple elements
    test.clear();
    test.offer( 1 );
    test.offer( 2 ); //  <----- This line causes bad memory access
}
```

ArrayList.h

```
#ifndef Testing_ArrayList_h
#define Testing_ArrayList_h

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <string>
using std::string;

using std::runtime_error;

using std::min;

template< typename E >
class ArrayList {

    friend class ArrayListTests;

private:

    /**
     * the maximum number of elements the current list can contain if it is not
     * resized
     */
    int m_arraySize;

    /**
     * the number of elements this list currently contains
     */
    int m_numElements;

    /**
     * the actual list of elements in this list
     */
    E* m_values;

    /**
     * Copies the contents of this array into a new array and replaces the old
     * array-based list with the new array. If the new array has smaller size
     * than the old array, then elements that do not fit into the new array
     * are discarded. If the new array size is less than 1, 1 is automatically
     * used as the new array size
     *
     * @param newArraySize       the new size of the elements array
     */
    void useResizedArray( int newArraySize ) {
        int arraySize = newArraySize;
        if ( arraySize < 1 ) {
            arraySize = 1;
        }
        E* newArr = new E[ arraySize ];

        cout << "Allocated " << newArr << endl;


        //copy elements into the new array
        int smallestSize = min( m_arraySize , arraySize );
        for ( int i=0 ; i<smallestSize ; i++ ) {
            newArr[ i ] = m_values[ i ];
        }

        //free memory of the old array
        cout << "Deleting " << m_values << endl;
        delete[] m_values;

        //update the list to have the new array and the new size
        m_values = newArr;
        m_arraySize = arraySize;
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the given index is out of bounds or not
     *
     * @param index                 an index
     * @return                      if the given index is out of bounds (greater
     *                              than the maximum element index, or less than
     *                              the minimum element index)
     */
    bool isOutOfBounds( int index ) const {
        return ( index < 0 || index >= m_numElements );
    }

protected:

    /**
     * Gets the maximum number of elements the current array can contain
     *
     * @return                      the current size of the array of this list
     */
    int getArraySize() const {
        return m_arraySize;
    }

public:

    /**
     * Creates a default ArrayList with no elements
     */
    ArrayList() {
        m_arraySize = 1;
        m_numElements = 0;
        m_values = new E[ 1 ];

        cout << "Allocated " << m_values << endl;

    }

    /**
     * Copies the contents of the given ArrayList into this ArrayList
     *
     * @param l                     the ArrayList to be copied
     */
    ArrayList( const ArrayList<E>& l ) {
        m_arraySize = l.m_arraySize;
        m_numElements = l.m_numElements;
        m_values = new E[ m_arraySize ];

        cout << "Allocated " << m_values << endl;

        for ( int idx=0 ; idx<l.size() ; idx++ ) {
            m_values[ idx ] = l.get( idx );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an ArrayList with the given initial size. If the given
     * initial size is less than 1, then 1 is automatically used
     * as the initial size.
     *
     * @param initialSize           initial number of array slots for
     *                              storing elements of the list
     */
    ArrayList( int initialSize ) {
        int arraySize = initialSize;
        if ( arraySize < 1 ) {
            arraySize = 1;
        }
        m_arraySize = arraySize;
        m_numElements = 0;
        m_values = new E[ arraySize ];

        cout << "Allocated " << m_values << endl;

    }

    ~ArrayList< E >() {

        cout << "Deleting " << m_values << endl;

        delete[] m_values;
    }

    /**
     * Copies the contents of the given ArrayList into this ArrayList
     */
    ArrayList<E>& operator=( const ArrayList<E>& listToCopy ) {
        m_arraySize = listToCopy.m_arraySize;
        m_numElements = listToCopy.m_numElements;
        E* newArr = new E[ m_arraySize ];

        cout << "Allocated " << newArr << endl;

        for ( int idx=0 ; idx<m_numElements ; idx++ ) {
            newArr[ idx ] = listToCopy.m_values[ idx ];
        }

        cout << "Deleting " << m_values << endl;

        delete[] m_values;
        m_values = newArr;
        return *this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the element at the given index
     *
     * @param index             the index of an element in the list
     * @return                  the element at the given index in the list
     * @throws error            if the index given is out of bounds
     */
    E& get( int index ) const {

        //make sure not we are not asked to go out of bounds
        if ( isOutOfBounds( index ) ) {
            throw runtime_error(
                                generateAccessOutOfBoundsMessage( index , m_numElements ) );
        }
        return m_values[ index ];
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the given element at the specified index
     *
     * @param index             the index in the ArrayList at which to insert
     *                          the given value
     * @param value             the value to insert
     * @throws error            if the index is out of bounds
     */
    void insert( int index , const E& value ) {

        //make sure we aren't asked to insert the value out of bounds
        //we allow insertion at the index following the last element
        //of the array, as that is equivalent to appending to the end
        if ( index < 0 || index > m_numElements ) {
            throw std::runtime_error(
                                     "insert out of bounds" );
        }

        //resize the elements array if we are over capacity
        //we resize it so that after the insert operation, we have exactly
        //twice as many empty slots as elements
        if ( m_numElements+1 > m_arraySize ) {
            useResizedArray( (m_numElements)*2 );
        }

        //shift all the elements including and after the given index
        //down by 1
        for ( int i=m_numElements-1 ; i>=index ; i-- ) {
            m_values[ i+1 ] = m_values[ i ];
        }

        //insert the new value
        m_values[ index ] = value;
        m_numElements++;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the given index of the list to contain the given element, and if
     * necessary, replaces an element that is currently there
     *
     * @param index             the index at which to set the new value
     * @param value             the new value to be set
     * @throws error            if the index is out of bounds
     */
    void set( int index , const E& value ) {
        if ( isOutOfBounds( index ) ) {
            throw std::runtime_error(
                                     generateAccessOutOfBoundsMessage(
                                                                                   index , m_numElements ) );
        }

        cout << "Writing to m_values at address " << &m_values[ index ] << endl;
        m_values[ index ] = value;
        cout << "Finish writing to m_values at address " << &m_values[ index ] << endl;
    }


    /**
     * Adds the given element to the end of the list
     *
     * @param value             the element to add
     */
    void append( const E& value ) {
        insert( m_numElements , value );
    }

    /**
     * Removes all elements from the ArrayList
     */
    void clear() {
        useResizedArray( 0 );
        m_numElements = 0;
        m_arraySize = 0;
    }

    int size() const {
        return this->m_numElements;
    }

    /**
     * Ensures that the ArrayList can contain the given number of elements
     * without resizing
     *
     * @param capacity          a minimum number of elements the list must
     *                          be able to contain without resizing
     */
    void ensureCapacity( int capacity ) {
        if ( capacity > m_arraySize ) {
            useResizedArray( capacity );
        }
    }

    string generateAccessOutOfBoundsMessage( int index , int size ) const { return ""; }

    string toString() const { return ""; }
};

#endif
```

ArrayQueue.h

```
#ifndef Testing_ArrayQueue_h
#define Testing_ArrayQueue_h

template< typename E >
class ArrayQueue : protected ArrayList< E > {

    friend class ArrayQueueTests;

private:

    /**
     * the index of the first element in the queue, which will be the first
     * element polled
     */
    int m_headIdx;

    /**
     * the index of the last element in the queue PLUS ONE.
     */
    int m_tailIdx;

    /**
     * the number of elements in the queue. we must store the number of elements
     * and not just calculate it from the index of the head and tail due to
     * wrap-around problems. if the head and tail indices are the same
     * then we cannot be sure if the queue has size 0, or if it has
     * reached full capacity.
     */
    int m_numElements;

    /**
     * Determines if the given index is out of bounds in the queue
     *
     * @return                  if the given element is
     */
    bool isOutOfBounds( int index ) const {
        return index < 0 || index >= m_numElements;
    }

    /**
     * Determines the index in the queue's underlying array, given the index
     * of an element in the queue
     *
     * @return                  the index in the queue converted to the index
     *                          in the array
     */
    int getIndexInArray( int queueIndex ) const {

        //queue size of 0 is special case, because we can't really define
        //wrapping around
        if ( m_numElements == 0 ) {
            return 0;
        }


        if ( queueIndex >= 0 ) {
            return (m_headIdx+queueIndex) % ArrayList< E >::getArraySize();
        }
        else {

            //if we are "unwrapping" around with a negative index
            //just keep adding the size of the array
            int wraparoundTimes = abs( queueIndex / m_numElements )+1;
            int offset = wraparoundTimes * m_numElements;
            return (m_headIdx + queueIndex + offset ) %
            ArrayList< E >::getArraySize();
        }
    }

public:
    /**
     * Constructs a default queue with no elements
     */
    ArrayQueue() : ArrayList< E >() {
        m_headIdx = 0;
        m_tailIdx = 0;
        m_numElements = 0;

        //we cannot have an array size of 0, because that would mess up
        //wrap around calculations
        ArrayList< E >::ensureCapacity( 1 );
    }

    /**
     * Puts the given value into the back of the queue
     *
     * @param value             the value to insert into the queue
     */
    void offer( const E& value ) {

        //if we exceed capacity, we might as well just resize the array
        //and start everything over with the head at the 0-th index
        if ( m_numElements+1 > ArrayList< E >::getArraySize() ) {
            E* tmp[ m_numElements ];
            for ( int i=0 ; i<m_numElements ; i++ ) {
                tmp[ i ] = &ArrayList< E >::get( (m_headIdx+i)%ArrayList< E >::getArraySize() );
            }
            ArrayList< E >::ensureCapacity( (m_numElements)*2 );
            for ( int i=0 ; i<m_numElements ; i++ ) {
                ArrayList< E >::set( i , *tmp[ i ] );
            }
            m_headIdx = 0;
            m_tailIdx = m_numElements;
        }

        //insert the element at the index of the tail
        int insertIdx = m_tailIdx % ArrayList< E >::getArraySize();

        //if the ArrayList representation already has an element at the
        //insertion index, just overwrite it
        if ( insertIdx < ArrayList< E >::size() ) {
            ArrayList< E >::set( insertIdx , value );
        }

        //if the ArrayList representation doesn't have an element at the
        //insertion index already, then we actually need to insert the
        //the new element. Otherwise, we'd get an access out of bounds
        //exception
        else {
            ArrayList< E >::insert( insertIdx , value );
        }

        m_tailIdx = (m_tailIdx+1) % ArrayList< E >::getArraySize();
        m_numElements++;
    }

    /**
     * Clears the queue so that it contains no elements
     */
    void clear() {
        ArrayList< E >::clear();
        m_headIdx = 0;
        m_tailIdx = -1;
        m_numElements = 0;

        //we cannot have an array size of 0 because that would mess up wrap
        //around calculations
        ArrayList< E >::ensureCapacity( 1 );
    }

    string toString() const { return ""; }
};


#endif
```

As Ben Voigt suggested, whenever something was allocated, I printed the address, and whenever something was deleted, I printed the address. The print statements are now incorporated into the ArrayList.h sample. I recompiled, and ran through Valgrind, and obtained the following output:

```
==2207== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2207== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2207== Using Valgrind-3.10.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2207== Command: ./a.out
==2207== 
Allocated 0x1000169f0
Allocated 0x100017a80
Deleting 0x1000169f0
Allocated 0x100017ad0
Deleting 0x100017a80
Allocated 0x100017b20
Deleting 0x100017ad0
Writing to m_values at address 0x100017b20
==2207== Invalid read of size 4
==2207==    at 0x100001640: ArrayList<int>::set(int, int const&) (ArrayList.h:251)
==2207==    by 0x100001243: ArrayQueue<int>::offer(int const&) (ArrayQueue.h:108)
==2207==    by 0x100000F99: main (main.cpp:38)
==2207==  Address 0x100017ad0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==2207==    at 0x4D9D: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:477)
==2207==    by 0x100001A4F: ArrayList<int>::useResizedArray(int) (ArrayList.h:73)
==2207==    by 0x1000014DD: ArrayList<int>::ensureCapacity(int) (ArrayList.h:287)
==2207==    by 0x100001211: ArrayQueue<int>::offer(int const&) (ArrayQueue.h:106)
==2207==    by 0x100000F99: main (main.cpp:38)
==2207== 
Finish writing to m_values at address 0x100017b20
Deleting 0x100017b20
==2207== 
==2207== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2207==     in use at exit: 29,316 bytes in 377 blocks
==2207==   total heap usage: 476 allocs, 99 frees, 35,952 bytes allocated
==2207== 
==2207== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2207==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2207==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2207==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2207==    still reachable: 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks
==2207==         suppressed: 25,220 bytes in 376 blocks
==2207== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==2207== 
==2207== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2207== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I see that Valgrind claimed I wrote to address 0x100017ad0, but my program says it wrote to address 0x100017b20. Yes, Valgrind is right in saying that 0x100017ad0 was free'd, because my program also reported that. But, my program was not writing to the address that Valgrind reported. How can this be reconciled?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `std::deque` or `std::queue`?

Comment: Could you give us a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: We don't know what else you're doing with this class.  We have no idea if copies are being made and you're not following the rule of 3.  Also, I don't recommend a new C++ programmer try things like this unless they know *all* the nuances in creating such a class.

Comment: `I ran unit tests in Xcode and in terminal, and did not get any problems.`  Unlike Java, bad code in C++ doesn't mean the code will crash -- you can still get a "positive" result on a unit test that consists of bad/wrong code.

Comment: I've added minimal code to the best of my ability, but it still seems a bit long. It won't compile.  Sorry about any hassles.

Comment: Please g++ main.cpp and run it though valgrind and you should get an error

Comment: The new code makes it look like you are doing things right. Try adding some printf debugging to show the pointer values from each allocation and deallocation.

Comment: @Ben Voigt I followed your advice, and after more debugging, I have determined that Valgrind and my program are reporting different addresses. My program says it wrote to 0x100017b20, but Valgrind says my program wrote to 0x100017ad0. I'm not really sure what to make of this... Since there have been so many long edits, would it be more appropriate to post this in a new question?

Comment: Actually, you do have a bug in the assignment operator for ArrayList - this may not affect the test case, but in case of self assignment your assignment operator will nuke the data then attempt to copy it. You really need to guard against self assignment in that assignment operator.

Comment: @user2570465: Note that Valgrind is complaining about the **read**, not the write. `value` is passed by reference, so it is meaningful to print `&value`.

Comment: @Timo Geusch Thanks for telling me of that. I had never actually heard of self assignment problems before you mentioned it. That special case eluded me in my test cases. I think I've fixed it now.

Comment: @user2570465, it certainly looks correct(er) :) now, but there is a much simpler way to deal with this - wrap the copy routine in a self assignment check. Something like `if (this != &listToCopy)` or similar. That way, you save yourself the unnecessary memory allocation and object copying, which can be pretty expensive in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, Valgrind is 100% right.  Here's the problem, in `ArrayQueue::offer`:

```
E* tmp[ m_numElements ];
for ( int i=0 ; i<m_numElements ; i++ ) {
    tmp[ i ] = &ArrayList< E >::get( (m_headIdx+i)%ArrayList< E >::getArraySize() );
}
```

Now `tmp` contains a bunch of pointers into the ArrayList contents

```
ArrayList< E >::ensureCapacity( (m_numElements)*2 );
```

The ArrayList may have moved its contents in the process of increasing capacity.

```
for ( int i=0 ; i<m_numElements ; i++ ) {
     ArrayList< E >::set( i , *tmp[ i ] );
}
```

Dereferencing the now-invalid pointers, which creates a wild reference (undefined behavior).  When `set` tries to get the value using that reference, BOOM!

I'm not sure what that loop is supposed to accomplish, since `ensureCapacity` calls `useResizedArray` which copies the items around as needed.  Oh, you're compacting the queue.  Well, that needs to be done using the new addresses only.  Also with the `%` modular addressing, make sure you don't overwrite an element before copying it.

Comment: Yes that fixed the problem. Thanks for all your help. Hopefully I can use the experience from this bug and fix the other errors that Valgrind has been pointing out.

Comment: @user2570465: Yeah, continue to use printf debugging to determine what valid addresses are, and read the Valgrind output really carefully, because a single line of C code often involves multiple memory accesses.